# Hide first Section

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog, popup

i have the following code. I want that the first part hides when i click on the button.
Can somebody help?

thank you in advance

````
&nbsp;</div>
<img src="https://sampleurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Brief.png" style="width:150px;height:91px;" /><br />
<style type="text/css">.myimgdivtoggle{ display:none;}
</style>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){   $(&#39;.togglebtn&#39;).click(function(){           $(&#39;.myimgdivtoggle&#39;).toggle();  });});</script><button class="togglebtn" type="button"><span class="cp_responsive cp_font" data-font-size="20px" style="font-size:20px;"><span data-font-size="18px"><span data-font-size="22px"><span data-font-size="20px"><span data-font-size="19px"><span style="font-family:lato;"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;" date-dismiss=“modal“ arialabel=“Close“>JETZT LESEN</span></span></span></span></span></span></span></button>
<div class="myimgdivtoggle"><img alt="display image on button click" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://sampleurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Krankmeldung_neu.jpg" /></div> ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You been to select the both image elements and toggle each inversely.

```
<div class="myimgdivtoggle2">
    <img src="https://sampleurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Brief.png" style="width:150px;height:91px;" /><br />
</div>
<button class="togglebtn" type="button">
    <span class="cp_responsive cp_font" data-font-size="20px" style="font-size:20px;">
        <span data-font-size="18px">
            <span data-font-size="22px">
                <span data-font-size="20px">
                    <span data-font-size="19px">
                        <span style="font-family:lato;">
                            <span style="color:#FFFFFF;" date-dismiss=“modal“ arialabel=“Close“>
                                JETZT LESEN
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</button>
<div class="myimgdivtoggle">
    <img alt="display image on button click" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://sampleurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Krankmeldung_neu.jpg" />
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .myimgdivtoggle2{ 
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $( ".togglebtn").click(function () {
                $( ".myimgdivtoggle" ).toggle();
                $( ".myimgdivtoggle2" ).toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply Phill. I have tried the code, but unfortunately it does not work. I want the whole first part to disappear when the second image is displayed. Maybe I need a new code? bootstrap modal popup or something.

Coding is not really my business, so I have a hard time with it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I have updated the answer, should work now